# safari position css not working

Tags: css, safari, background-position

We are working on a new website and are having an issue with the "Join the Conversation" box in Safari only. Works fine on other browsers. The background is only suppose to appear on the bottom of the box, but in Safari, it displays on the entire box:
http://futurethink.colorandinformationdev.com

The old dev site is here, and it displays fine on Safari and other browsers. I did a diff check between the home page and css, but can't figure this one out:
http://cool-quotes.org/future

```
#email_newsletter.home_content {
   background:#fff url(img/addons/news_letter_container_bg.png) repeat-x left bottom;
   overflow: hidden !important;
   border:1px solid #B3B3B3;
   /* */ 
}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing your issue, looks the same to me in Firefox, Chrome and Safari...

Comment: i edited this question,but after bounty doesn't show my edits, i want to put image with background-position: right 100px bottom 0px; it works in chrome but not in safari

Comment: i asked new question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908471/safari-position-css-not-working-second-time-ask-same-quastion

Comment: Which version of Safari? Note that the last version for Windows is over a year old, and it might not support all of the latest CSS.

Comment: try to use the position property and z-index hope that will help you  or check the browser updates

Answer (score 1):

According to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp) you can provide the values in the below format:

- **right top / right center / right bottom** : only specify one keyword
- xpos ypos : Units can be pixels (0px 0px) or any other [CSS units](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)
- inherit : Specifies that the setting of the background-position property should be inherited from the parent element

Also I've tried your stuffs personally and I've found that its really not working out for Safari, but if it is really necessary for you and if you can do the below mentioned trick then your issue is solved :-)

**Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZkBb2/) for you**

```
<!-- The CSS -->
<style type="text/css">
div {
background: url(https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo4w.png) no-repeat scroll right bottom transparent;
margin-right: 100px;
}
p {
margin-right: -100px;
}
</style>

<!-- The HTML -->
<div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In euismod adipiscing elementum. In turpis ipsum, adipiscing vitae magna vitae, consequat hendrerit justo. Aliquam non facilisis dui, tempus convallis tortor. Donec ultricies pharetra tortor, a tempor magna commodo nec. Donec id justo ornare, ullamcorper est ac, aliquet justo. Duis rutrum justo a laoreet volutpat. Phasellus molestie consequat risus at varius. Aenean imperdiet ornare odio, a aliquam leo pharetra id. Integer lectus felis, semper id sapien viverra, dignissim molestie massa. Mauris blandit eros eget lorem cursus, sed consectetur lectus tincidunt. Cras tristique vel orci eu cursus. Sed congue tempor venenatis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Maecenas vehicula nec eros sit amet mollis. Nam ipsum arcu, pretium et tempus ac, scelerisque sed nulla. Sed dapibus in massa in consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Cheers & Goodluck!

Comment: The W3Schools page is outdated. Better not use it. The official W3C page is [here](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-backgrounds/#background-position).

Comment: I agree with @mr-lister. W3CSchools is notorious for having bad information. Check [this](http://www.w3fools.com/) out.

Comment: @BrianRay No it isn't. Some people would like it to be, but there are many tutorial type sites that are as bad or worse. There is no good reason for singling out W3Schools as "the bad one".

Answer (score 0):

Try this !

```
#email_newsletter .home_content {
   background: #ffffff url('img/addons/news_letter_container_bg.png') left bottom repeat-x;
   width: 600px;
   height: 400px;
   float: left;
   overflow: hidden !important;
   border:1px solid #B3B3B3;
   /* */ 
  }
```